# Как получить id ресурса, используемого конкретным View?

Tags: android, view

Добрый день. 
У меня есть View типа ImageView.
Этот ImageView использует конкретный ресурс — файл в папке drawable. 
Я хочу найти способ, с помощью которого можно будет получить id используемого ресурса. 
Я могу получить id самого ImageView с помощью iv.getId(), но для ресурса такого же метода почему-то нет. Я могу только использовать iv.getDrawable(), однако в конец этой связки почему-то невозможно добавить .getId().
if (iv.getDrawable() == getDrawable(R.drawable.compas)) { ... }
Этот вариант почему-то не делает того, что ожидается. Условие не выполняется, хотя по идее и слева, и справа находится один и тот же объект. 
Буду очень благодарен, если поможете понять, как id используемого ресурса из view.

Answer (score 2):

Можно поступить следующим образом:

В объект ImageView добавить тег с drawable.id

```
imageView.setTag(R.drawable.icon);
```

При необходимости можно будет получить id ресурса его из тега ImageView

```
int drawableId = (int) imageView.getTag();
```

Если нет уверенности, что у всех ImageView будет тег, то перед вызовом метода getTag() надо сделать проверку на то, что imageView.getTag() != null

Answer (score 0):

Могу только подсказать, как проверить `Drawable` на совпадение правильно.

```
if (iv.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getDrawable(R.drawable.compas).getConstantState())){...}
```